# How to remove hash from routes in react-admin Framework

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin frontend Framework, and would like to know if there is a way to remove the '#' from routes. I'm using customRoutes properties to provide a collection of routes for our system.

````
<Admin
    title="my title"
    menu={Menu}
    theme={theme}
    dashboard={Ledgers}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    authProvider={Authorization}
    dataProvider={DataProviders}
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    locale="en"
    appLayout={Layout}
    customRoutes={Routes}
>
    <Resource name="users" list={Users} />
</Admin>```
````

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own history function (compatible with the history npm package), and pass it to the  component to override the default history strategy. For instance, to use browserHistory:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

const App = () => (
    <Admin history={history}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```

Comment: `Warning: Please use "require("history").createBrowserHistory" instead of "require("history/createBrowserHistory")". Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.`